# Matlab mex lstdc++ not found

Tags: software-installation, gcc, matlab

I'm trying to compile a mex file in matlab. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Matlab R2014b. 
The first dependency issue I faced was the GCC which needed a version 4.7.x, while my system was running 4.8.x. I fixed that by changing mexopts.sh and putting that in my Matlab/R2014 path.
Now, I get this error:

```
mex ic.c -largeArrayDims -v
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)
   **FILE = /home/kyouma/.matlab/R2014b/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------**
->    MATLAB                = /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b
->    CC                    = gcc-4.7
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
         arguments          = 
->    CXX                   = g++-4.7
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          = 
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          = 
->    LD                    = gcc-4.7
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64
         arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         **arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------**

-> gcc-4.7 -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -O -DNDEBUG  "ic.c"

-> gcc-4.7 -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o  "ic.mexa64"  ic.o  -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "ic.mexa64"' failed.

Unable to complete successfully.
```

I tried looking for it, but all the libstdc++ issues I found seem to have something to do with the 6.4 version, and mine doesn't pop any error that seems specific as to the version.

I am new to ubuntu, so any light anyone can throw on this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually install g++-4.7? or just gcc-4.7?

Comment: I updated and upgraded ubuntu, and I checked which version of gcc 4.7 was running, it said gcc 4.7.3 was on.
I troubleshooted it and I followed what I found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/137228-setup-mex-compiler-for-r2014a-for-linux

Answer (score 1):

I had to install g++. @steeldriver, thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)
I specifically installed a version 4.7 of g++ because my gcc that matlab needed was only 4.7.x,and the mex compilations with my version of matlab were not compatible with the default 4.8 that ubuntu 14.04 runs.